# Uninstalling Windows 7 from multi boot system with ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, uninstall

My laptop has Ubuntu and Windows 7 installed. I want to remove Windows 7 completely to use only Ubuntu. How can I uninstall Windows 7?

Comment: The first step delete the partition with Windows.  The second step edit the list of detectable operating system that Grub detects manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything you want from Ubuntu:-

- Copy off any files you need from the W7 partition.
- Either reformat the W7 partition, or delete it and move the Ubuntu boundary to use the released space (using **gparted**).
- Type `update-grub` from a root shell to remove the W7 boot entry.

If you have an OEM licence for W7, make sure you have the installation / recovery disc and product key, in case you ever want to go back to it. If you have a retail licence, before you wipe the partition you may have to do something to deregister it, so that you can install it on another machine, but you will have to check with MS, as I have never done this.